# how to display div one by one using css

Tags: html, css, chat

we are developing chat application in that chat how much content will have that much width we want displaying separately one by one. and also chat length is big displaying of chat content in multi line.

We are displaying the content and how much content have that much size of width div displaying but side by side div is coming. we want to display step by step how to do.and if content length is long then displaying to multi line.

```css
.right {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
}

.right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.right::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  right: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="right">
  <span>thanks</span>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <span>thanks</span>
</div>

</div>

<div>
<div class="right">
  <span>thanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanks</span>
</div>



</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Really, for a chat app, who would ever use a word that long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `word-break:break-all`(or normal|break-all|keep-all) Break words between any two letters.
and use `clear` property control the behavior of floating elements.

```css
.right {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
}
.right span{
  word-break: break-all;
}
.fix{
  clear:both;
  
}

.right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.right::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  right: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix">
<div class="right">
  <span>thanks</span>
</div>
  </div>
<div class="fix">

<div class="right">
  <span>thanks</span>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fix">
<div class="right">
  <span>thanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanksthanks</span>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear the right float with `overflow: hidden;` for instance.

```
<div class="clear">
  <div class="right">
    <span>thanks</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
  <div class="right">
    <span>thanks</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
  <div class="right">
    <span>thregre gerg ergr geg reger ger gergregeg erger gerg erg erg ergergerger ge anks</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.clear { overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4q1azw3/6/)

Comment: can you see the my second problem, in screen shot i mention

Comment: Did you try using the HTML structure I suggest with a `.clear` div around each content ?

Comment: I think I see. Use a `margin-right` instead of `right` to avoid the cut of the border : https://jsfiddle.net/L4q1azw3/6/

Comment: second problem is not working js fiddle is fine but when i integrate in my code it is not working

Comment: Did you change `right` by `margin-right` of `.right` class ?

Comment: vincent 2nd problem also resolved used  word break css propert